Overexposed white bar at right of scan - Plustek OpticFilm 7600i sensor damaged?
I'm in the process of scanning our family memories (negative film and slides). I haven't been using my Plustek OpticFilm 7600i scanner for a while and now I am having occasional image artifacts at the rightmost part of the scan.
In such scans, a white bar of varying width appears at the rightmost part of a scan, typically a couple mm from the image edge.
Initially I thought that this was a problem with a misalignment of the top and bottom parts of the film holder, yielding ghosting when the LED lighting is being reflected to a flat edge not fully covered by a misaligned to side of the film holder.
However, when performing a preview in Vuescan without any film or slide holder, I noticed a well-delinated vertical bar close to the rightmost edge of the scanning window. You can also see slightly uneven lighting from the LED lighting unit:

Here's a greatly exaggerated portion of the same image at full width, cropped in height:

The vertical white bar is clearly demarcated (no soft edge), and there are still apparently some 'unafffected' pixels to the right of this defect.
Today I disassembled my 7600i scanner to see whether a dust bunny was the cause of the imaging artifact. When doing a preview with the LED light holder unmounted, I got a preview image with color noise and also showing a brighter vertical bar in the image preview (no screenshot alas). At least, this means that the LED light unit isn't the cause of the image artifact in my scans.
I gave the optical parts a dusting with a rocket blaster and then reassembled the scanner. Unfortunately the imaging artifact persists.
Does this look like a broken CCD sensor in the scanner? I doubt that this is something that I can repair.

Is this when scanning negatives?  That could rule out this just being the film holder.

It is most visible when scanning film negatives. When scanning framed slides the artifact is less visible.
